# Static Swift framework fails CocoaPods validation with `Undefined symbols for architecture`

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, static-framework

I am using Xcode 12.2, and working on a Swift static framework (embedded in a `.xcframework` in the end), which I intend to deliver with CocoaPods.

My issue is currently not the CocoaPods integration in an app project (`pod install` works correctly and app builds & run), but the pod validation with `pod lib lint` command.

The `lint` validation fails, with logs containing the following:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAccelerate'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtCs12_SwiftObject", referenced from:
[...]
```

And log contains the same with
`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64`

My `.podspec` file is the following

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MyFramework'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'

  s.source           = { :git => 'https://url-to-repo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  
  s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
  s.platform = :ios
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
    
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.static_framework = true
      
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = "MyFramework.xcframework"
  
  s.frameworks = 'AVFoundation', 'Accelerate', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreImage'
  
  s.ios.library = 'z', 'c++'
end
```

My guess is that the project that CocoaPods creates is with Objective-C, and there would be probably no reference to the Swift compiler or libraries.
But I have no clues how to fix this..

I've been losing days on this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, for the validation of a podspec, CocoaPods create an Objective-C Xcode project.

A Swift-only framework having a `Mach-O Type` with `Static Library` is indeed an issue on CocoaPods' side, because it can't handle it yet.
In this situation, the Swift libraries are not linked.

An issue has been opened and addressed on [CocoaPods repository](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8649), and the fix will come with [CocoaPods version 1.11](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/milestone/56)

Until this CocoaPods 1.11 release, here are the workarounds shared in this issue (I haven't tried them):

- [Include a `.swift` file in your pod](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8649#issuecomment-489339822)
- [Add tests to the podspec, having those tests depend on a swift pod, without adding any source files, and execute pod `lib lint` with the option `--skip-tests`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8649#issuecomment-536486958)

  In your podspec add:

  ```
    # Adding tests with a swift dependency is a workaround in order to make pod lib lint work
    # See: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8649
    spec.test_spec 'Tests' do |spec|
      spec.dependency 'Result', '~> 5.0'
    end
  ```

Also fyi, there is no options to allow a `pod push` if the `lint` fails for the simple reason it would be considered as an anti-pattern.